# Deparse value of a function passed to a secondary function

Tags: r

I have a function, defined as follows

```r
fn1 <- function(var = NULL) {
  if (missing(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var))
}
```

I can call this function and it gives me what I want.

```r
fn1()                                                                                                                                                
# NULL

fn1(test)                                                                                                                                            
# [1] "test"
```

I now want to functionalise the deparsing of `var`.

```r
fn2 <- function(var = NULL) {
  deparse_var(var)
}

deparse_var <- function(var) {
  if (missing(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var))
}
```

But this does not give me the intended result

```r
fn2()                                                                                                                                                
# [1] "var"

fn2(test)                                                                                                                                            
# [1] "var"
```

Since I have the value of `var` inside `deparse_var()`, I can check whether or not it is `NULL`. But the `deparse` does not work if it isn't.

```r
deparse_var <- function(var) {
  if (is.null(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var))
}

fn2()
# [1] NULL

fn2(test)
# Error in deparse_var(var) : object 'test' not found
```

Answer (score 3):

We can substitute on the first frame

```
deparse_var <- function(var) {
  if (is.null(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var, sys.frame(1)))
}

fn2 <- function(var = NULL) {
  deparse_var(var)
}
fn2()  
#NULL 

fn2(test)   
#[1] "test"
```

Or using `missing`

```
deparse_var <- function(var) {
   if (missing(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var, sys.frame(1)))
 }

fn2()
#[1] "NULL"
fn2(test)
#[1] "test"
```

In order to rectify the "NULL" to `NULL`, an `if/else` can be added.  From @nathaneastwood's comments

```
deparse_var <- function(var) {
  res <- if (missing(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var, sys.frame(1))) 
  if (res == "NULL" && is.null(var)) NULL else res
}
```

Comment: Yes - this is the one. I was trying to use `parent.frame()` and wasn't having any joy. Thanks :)

Comment: Just checking this, the first solution doesn't work. The second solution returns a character `"NULL"` instead of an actual `NULL`.

Comment: @nathaneastwood Could this be due to the R version as I couldn't get the error you showed in your post with your original function?  I am using `R 3.6.2`  Regarding the second case, you could have an  `if/else` .e. `v1 <- deparse_var(var); if(v1 == "NULL")  NULL else v1`

Comment: I did wonder whether it was the R version that might be the issue. I'm on 3.6.3. The additional `if/else` works and you can actually place it within `deparse_var()`. Obviously it is a bit hacky, but it would work I guess.

Comment: It could be.  For the  second option, it is just an  `if/else` statement is needed

Comment: `deparse_var <- function(var) {
  res <- if (missing(var)) var else deparse(substitute(var, sys.frame(1)));
  if (res == "NULL" && is.null(var)) NULL else res;
}`
This would work.

Comment: @nathaneastwood i cannot  crosscheck with R 3.6.3 as of now  bcz i have some things that depend on R 3.6.2 versioini

Comment: Very odd. I get the same error in 3.4.4 as well. I will try to check 3.6.2 today.

Answer (score 1):

How about the below? Should work for missing, NULL and others.

```r
deparse_var <- function(var) {
  if (missing(var)) return(NULL)
  res <- deparse(substitute(var, sys.frame(1L))) 
  if (!identical(res, "NULL")) res
}
```

Note: You may want to adjust the visibility of the result as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this post. I continued to have issues with the solutions posted. However the below solution does work.

```r
deparse_var <- function(var) {
  sub_var <- eval(substitute(substitute(var)), parent.frame())
  if (is.symbol(sub_var)) var <- as.character(sub_var)
  var
}
```

You can see the results below

```r
fn2 <- function(var = NULL) {
  deparse_var(var)
}

fn2()
[1] NULL

fn2(test)
[1] "test"

fn2("test")
[1] "test"
```